# Asp.Net MVC 5 Identity how to not list users which have Admin role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

There are three tables which are related to roles.

1. **AspNetUsers** - keeps the `UserId` data
2. **AspNetRoles** - keeps the `RoleName` and `RoleId`
3. **AspNetUserRoles** - makes a relation through AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles. It has only two cloumns which are `UserId` and `RoleId`. But for some reason I couldn't access to this table directly (like `db.UserRoles`).

So what I'am trying to do is avoid listing the users which are in the Admin role.

My code is like this:

```
return View(db.Users.OrderBy(e => e.UserName)
                    .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

I think I should make something like this but I always get errors when I do it this way

```
return View(db.Users.Where(e => e.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleId != "1"))
                    .OrderBy(e => e.UserName)
                    .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
                     // suppose that the RoleId of Admin is 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return View(db.Users.Where(e => e.Roles.All(r => r.RoleId != "1"))
                  .OrderBy(e => e.UserName).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)); 
                    // Suppowse that the RoleId of Admin is 1
```

Use the `.All` extension

Or `db.Users.Where(u=>!u.Roles.Any(r=>r.RoleId == "1"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const int adminRoleId = 1;
var query = db.Users.Where(user => !user.Roles
                                        .Any(role => role.Id 
                                                        == adminRoleId));
return View(query.OrderBy(e => e.UserName)
                 .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

I think that in your case the problem is caused by `r.RoleId != "1"`, I think that `RoleId` is of `int` type. What;s more, the expression `Where(e => e.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleId != "1"))` is invalid. Expression tree passed into first `Where` should return `bool` for specified `r` (it is user in your context) but you are returniing collection of roles different than admin (instead of mentioned `bool`).